# How to pass params from rails RSpec view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a view spec under `spec/views/interests/show.html.slim_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "interests/show", type: :view do
  interest = FactoryBot.create(:interest)

  before(:each) do
    assign(:interest, interest)
  end

  it "renders attributes in <td>" do
    render template: "interests/show"
    expect(rendered).to match(/interest 1/)
  end
end
```

the corresponding view file `app/views/interests/show.html.slim`

```
- content_for :page_title do
  h2 View enquiry

= render "interests/interest", interest: @interest

= link_to "Back", edit_job_path(params[:job_id])
```

When I run the spec I get the below error

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

The error is at the line `link_to "Back", edit_job_path(params[:job_id])`

I tried the below solutions,

1. assign params

```
assign(params[:id], 1)
or
assign(params[:job_id], 1)
```

2. pass params in render

```
render template: "interests/show", params: { id: 1 }
or
render template: "interests/show", params: { job_id: 1 }
```

Both don't work.

Comment: your params should have key `:job_id` not `:id`

Comment: Yeah tried. It's not working

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your routes file?

Comment: for jobs it's just `resources :jobs`.

route would be  `edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)   jobs#edit`

Comment: Do you need to use a named a named parameter here `link_to "Back", edit_job_path(id: params[:job_id])`?